# How Do I carry dropdown value selected in Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Hi I have Dropdown in Index page where user needs to select lists. Values are coming from Database. I took this dropdown value into session so I can carry this to Httppost.

Below is my code in Index page :

```
 var activitydropdown = orderdata.uspApp_ActivityPageReportname(Convert.ToInt32(newid)).ToList();

              List<SelectListItem> activitypage = new List<SelectListItem>();

              if (activitydropdown != null && activitydropdown.Count > 0)
                {
              foreach (var activityresults in activitydropdown)
              {
                  activitypage.Add(new SelectListItem
                  {
                      Text = activityresults.name,
                      Value = activityresults.id.ToString(),
                  });


                  }
              }


              ViewData["activitydropdown"] = activitypage;
              Session["activitydropdown"] = activitypage;
```

And this is my code in view :

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Automation", new { step = "2" }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmIndex" }))
                              {

                              @Html.DropDownList("DrpaActivity", ViewData["activitydropdown"] as List<SelectListItem>, "All", new { style = "margin-left:694px;margin-bottom:20px;", onchange = "submit();" })
```

Now when user selects list from dropdown, i need to carry that text to my httpost index. Now in httpost index, in debug mode if i see this code :

```
 var sessionlistautomation = Session["activitydropdown"];
```

I can see text and value and selected is false for every item. So how can i carry text here selected from Index to httpost, so when user selects list from dropdown, it stores that text value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be available in your Request i.e.

```
Request["DrpaActivity"]
```

However I would strongly advise using ViewModels instead as they're typesafe, less room for error and easier to use.

If you create a view model, like below:

```
public class AViewModel
{
    public string DrpaActivity { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> ActivitySelectList { get; set; }
}
```

In your Index you can return it like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   var model = new AViewModel();

   // set the select list i.e.
   model.ActivitySelectList = // get from db etc


   return View(model);      

}
```

Then in your view declare the model at the top

```
@model AViewModel
```

...

Set your dropdown like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DrpaActivity, Model.ActivitySelectList as List<SelectListItem>, "All", new { style = "margin-left:694px;margin-bottom:20px;", onchange = "submit();" })
```

You can then get your selected drop-down in your post as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(AViewModel model)
{
    var isValid = model.DrpaActivity;
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Hi I got this. Now I have id what user selects in dropdown. Can you show me how can i save text based on this id??

Comment: I got it. Appreciate your time. I did like if id == id, then selected = true. It seems easy to me.

Comment: Nice one, yeah. You can set the selected Id on your get call and it will automatically select it. Good luck with the rest.

Comment: Where's the "submit()" function? How is the model notified of changes? Also, do you define the model in its own file?